# If I have a 3d grid of cubes, how can I efficiently find all the cubes that intersect a sphere of radius r and position p?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

Imagine you have a 3D space between 0 and **d** meters in the x,y and z directions (it's a cube of length **d**). now let's assume I want to break this up into a 3D array of smaller cubes. We want **n** cubes in each direction. This means each cube has a length, width and height of **d**/**n** (you can assume that d/n divides perfectly).
This can be held in the following array:

`Cube* cubes[n][n][n];`

Now let us assume we can have a sphere of radius **r** and position **p**, where **p** can be anywhere inside the 3d space, and **r** has no constraints. What is the most efficient way of finding and returning all the cubes that intersect with this sphere?

Currently, I am looping through all the cubes in the array and using the Pythagorean theorem to check the distance between each cube and **p**, which I wrote the pseudo code for below.

```
Cube* getIntersectingCubes(r,p) { 
    Cube* cubes[n][n][n];
    Cube* result[];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++) {
                if(distanceBetween(cubes[i][j][k],p) < r) {
                    result.add(cubes[i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, there is definitely a better way to do this. How could I return the same output but check as few cubes as possible?

Comment: Have a `bool` for each `Cube*` pointer in a `std::map<Cube*,bool>` to indicate already visited cubes.

Comment: Some variation on a Bresenham's algorithm comes to mind first.

Comment: `Cube* cubes[n][n][n];` -- What is the maximum value of `n`?  If this is one of those variable length array things, then you are risking a stack overflow if `n` is large enough.

Comment: n will be a constant. I just haven't decided what it is yet. I assume it will be less than d though

Comment: You start with a chosen coordinate system. You know `r`. You then stack boxes and can eliminate all where `r > farthest_extent_of_box` and get rid of those where `r < close_extent_of_box`. The sphere intersects all that are left over. (you need to do this at least twice (1) origin in between boxes; and (2) origin at center of box. If you start out with a paper and pencil, it will cut your coding time dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still having trouble working out a coordinate system and your algorithm, start with a diagram:

[image]

Essentially what you have is a 3D grid of cubes and your points `p` can be chosen any way you like so long as they describe a cube completely. What you want to determine is for which cubes does the radius `r` intersect any part of the cube. You can handle that with three vectors. You simply treat the cube origin as a vector. You know the lengths of the sides of each cube (`d / n`) you can use to form a second vector (call it the extent of `p` or `p_extent`) which you can add to the origin vector to determine the farthest point in the cube. So `p_extent` would equal `d/n`**i** + `d/n`**j** + `d/n`**k**.

You can create a struct to help in handling the coordinates as a vector, e.g.:

```
typedef struct {
    double x, y, z;
} vect_pos;
```

With your two vectors, you can simply add them together (e.g. `p` + `p_extent`) to form a vector describing the farthest point in the cube from the origin. (you want the direction of the vector inside your cube to have the same sign direction as your origin vector (so you can simply multiply it with a unit vector in that direction). For example is your point is `-3`**i** `-1`**j** and `2`**k**, you can multiple by the `p_extent` vector by `-1`**i** `-1`**j** `1`**k**. (picture the *cube origin* vector in each of the 8-quadrants and the values that `x, y, z` would have in each.

To add two `vector_pos` together, you can simply use vector addition, e.g.

```
/* vector addition */
vect_pos vect_add (const vect_pos *a, const vect_pos *b)
{
    vect_pos c = { .x = 0. };
    
    c.x = a->x + b->x;
    c.y = a->y + b->y;
    c.z = a->z + b->z;
    
    return c;
}
```

The last wrinkle that choosing the coordinate at a corner of the cube will require you solve is that the origin vector will not always point to the corner closest to the origin (picture in the diagram above where `p` would point if you rotated the origin counter-clockwise by 90 deg about the axis. (your alternative is to choose the center of the cube as its origin, but then you have twice the number of calculations).

You can handle the closest corner issue by a simple check and shifting the corner for the origin by a cube side length for purposes of the calculation of whether `r` is between the closest and farthest corners (the cube is still the same cube) With your cube origin and the farthest corner described, you can simply use the vector-distance formula to calculate the distance each is from the origin and if `r` is between the two, the sphere intersects that cube.

To choose the closest point to the origin before calculating the distances you can use:

```
/* point in cube closest to origin */
vect_pos closest_pt (const vect_pos *p, const int len)
{
    vect_pos c = {  p->x >= 0 ? p->x : p->x + len,
                    p->y >= 0 ? p->y : p->y + len,
                    p->z >= 0 ? p->z : p->z + len  };
    
    return c;
}
```

(choosing your cube at origin `0, 0, 0` with positive sides allows you to simply add a cube side length in the case that coordinate is negative to choose the closest point on the cube as the origin)

and for the distance calculations, a simple square-root of the sum of the squares:

```
/* vector distance */
double vect_dist (const vect_pos *p)
{
    return sqrt (p->x * p->x + p->y * p->y + p->z * p->z);
}
```

To check if `r` falls between the closest and farthest distance within each cube you can put it altogether with a short function that handles choosing the extent vector in the same direction as the origin, adds the vectors and then compares the distances of each to `r`, e.g.

```
/* does r intersect cube at postition p */
int intersect (vect_pos *p, const double r, const int len)
{
    vect_pos c = closest_pt (p, len),                   /* closest pt to origin */
            p_extent = { .x = c.x >= 0 ? len : -len,    /* length, unit vector */
                         .y = c.y >= 0 ? len : -len,    /* pointing outward */
                         .z = c.z >= 0 ? len : -len },
             p_farthest = vect_add (&c, &p_extent);     /* farthest point in cube */
    double   nearest  = vect_dist (&c),                 /* distance to nearest */
             farthest = vect_dist (&p_farthest);        /* distance to farthest */
    
    return nearest <= r && r <= farthest;               /* return radius in between */
}
```

That's basically it. You can add a short function to output the points to as a convenience, e.g.

```
void prn_pos (const vect_pos *p)
{
    printf ("(% d, % d, % d)\n",
            (int)p->x, (int)p->y, (int)p->z);
}
```

and then add a `main()` that allows entry of `r`, `d` and `n` and outputs the results:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    double  r = argc > 1 ? strtod (argv[1], NULL) : .9;     /* r */
    int     d = argc > 2 ? strtol (argv[2], NULL, 0) : 1,   /* d */
            n = argc > 3 ? strtol (argv[3], NULL, 0) : d,   /* n */
            dn = 0,             /* d/n */
            nc = 0,             /* number of cubes in each direction */
            total = 0,          /* total cubes in search grid */
            intersecting = 0;   /* number of cubes that intersect sphere */
    
    if (r < 0 || d < 0) {   /* validate length inputs */
        fputs ("error: negtive length in input of r or d.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!n || n < 0) {      /* validate n not zero or negative */
        fputs ("error: n - divide by zero or negative.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (d < r) {            /* ensure d >= r */
        int min_d = ceil (r);
        n *= min_d / d;
        d = min_d;
    }
    if (d % n) {            /* validate d equally divisible by n */
        fputs ("error: d not equally divisible by n.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    dn = d / n;                     /* cube side length */
    nc = ceil (r / dn) + 1;         /* limit of cubes needed per-direction */
    total = nc * nc * nc * 8;       /* total number of cubes in search grid */
    
    printf ("\nOut of %d cubes, the following intersect sphere of radius %.2f\n\n",
            total, r);
    
    for (int i = -d; i <= d; i += dn)               /* loop -d to d */
        for (int j = -d; j <= d; j += dn)
            for (int k = -d; k <= d; k += dn) {
                vect_pos p = { i, j, k };           /* vector to cube origin */
                if (intersect (&p, r, dn)) {        /* does it intersect sphere? */
                    prn_pos (&p);                   /* output cube origin */
                    intersecting++;                 /* increment count */
                }
            }
    
    printf ("\nintersecting cubes: %d\n", intersecting);
}
```

Add the headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

and then compile linking against the math library `-lm` and you have a working program to test. If no arguments for `r`, `d` or `n` are provided, the code uses `.90`, `1`, and `1` as defaults. Note the loop limits are at minimum from `-(next int above r)` to `(next int above r)` in each dimension or as given by `d` whichever is greater and not shorter than `r`.

**Example Use/Output**

Default case with `r = .9` and `d = 1` and `n = 1`:

```
$ ./bin/cube-sphere-intersect

Out of 64 cubes, the following intersect sphere of radius 0.90

(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1,  0)
(-1,  0, -1)
(-1,  0,  0)
( 0, -1, -1)
( 0, -1,  0)
( 0,  0, -1)
( 0,  0,  0)

intersecting cubes: 8
```

If you draw the cubes out on a grid, those are the 8 cubes surrounding the origin.

Choosing `r = 5.5`, `d = 6` and `n = 1` would give the same result other than the sides of the cubes being of different length:

```
$ ./bin/cube-sphere-intersect 5.5 6 1

Out of 64 cubes, the following intersect sphere of radius 5.50

(-6, -6, -6)
(-6, -6,  0)
(-6,  0, -6)
(-6,  0,  0)
( 0, -6, -6)
( 0, -6,  0)
( 0,  0, -6)
( 0,  0,  0)

intersecting cubes: 8
```

If you enter an `r` length of exacly `1`, then this is where your choice of whether to consider `r` equal to the min or max length will come into play. There are arguments for saying "touching" a cube doesn't really mean it intersects as the point will technically lie on a tangent that distance out, but there are equally good arguments that say that intersects (the choice of whether you want to use `<=` or `<` in the comparison is left to you)

For example if you enter anything between `1.0 < sqrt(2)` (`1.414...`) you will find 32 cube intersect, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/cube-sphere-intersect 1.1

Out of 216 cubes, the following intersect sphere of radius 1.10

(-2, -1, -1)
(-2, -1,  0)
(-2,  0, -1)
(-2,  0,  0)
(-1, -2, -1)
(-1, -2,  0)
(-1, -1, -2)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1,  0)
(-1, -1,  1)
(-1,  0, -2)
(-1,  0, -1)
(-1,  0,  0)
(-1,  0,  1)
(-1,  1, -1)
(-1,  1,  0)
( 0, -2, -1)
( 0, -2,  0)
( 0, -1, -2)
( 0, -1, -1)
( 0, -1,  0)
( 0, -1,  1)
( 0,  0, -2)
( 0,  0, -1)
( 0,  0,  0)
( 0,  0,  1)
( 0,  1, -1)
( 0,  1,  0)
( 1, -1, -1)
( 1, -1,  0)
( 1,  0, -1)
( 1,  0,  0)

intersecting cubes: 32
```

Then for radius between `sqrt(2) <= sqrt(3)` you would find 56 cube intersect and so on.

This is just one way to implement it. If you are curious, go rewrite it to use the center of each cube as the origin of the cube. You don't have to use a struct, you can just operate on each `x, y, z` directly, but the struct helps keep the logic clear. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer:

Assume the entire domain as a single cube:

1. Figure out if there is an intersection
2. If so, divide into octants and repeat (1)

Because you only need to search the octants where an intersection is present, you won't have to preallocate a massive array of cells.

The intersection algorithm can be simplified to any cube where at least one of the nodes is less than the radius from `p` and at least one is greater. It should be possible to write this algorithm in a way that is easy to vectorise.

---

*Note:* Probably don't want to store your 3d array on the stack, even if you pick a relatively small number for n, say 50, that's already 125000 doubles, enough to cause a stack overflow on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the cube containing point `p` and go into any one direction while given cube still intersects the sphere. That would give you a distance +-1 to all "edge" cubes.

This provides early termination of the search through cubes you know won't intersect and gives you an approximation of end points in all directions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a cube is in the outer shell if it intersects the sphere but isn't fully contained in the sphere. Say the initial point p = (x, y, z). We'll proceed by finding the cubes in the outer shell. Given these, it's easy to find interior cubes.

```
1. Find the cube containing p in O(1).
2. Find the most distant cube intersecting the sphere that can be reached by decreasing x.
3. Add this to a set: unexplored
4. repeatedly do the following (each iteration is O(1):
    a. Pull a cube from unexplored.
    b. Add any neighbors that intersect the outer shell and aren't explored to unexplored.
    c. Mark the current cube as explored.
```

How long does this take? It's linear with the surface area of the sphere measured in cubes, so O(4*pi*(r/d)^2) = O((r/d)^2). I.e. the formula for the surface area of a sphere, but with the radius measured in cubes.

If it suffices to return the outer shell then you're done. If you need to return the contents then this grows to be linear with the output, which is O((r/d)^3)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a function that will map any point in 3D into three integers:

```
  (x,y,z) -> (floor(x/dx), floor(y/dy), floor(z/dz))
```

where, in your case, *dx = dy = dz = d/n* is the size (along axes x, y, z) of small cubes (which I shall rather call "cells") you divide the whole space into. This function maps any point in 3D  into a discrete cell.

Now, you should find the minimum cuboid, which is made of cells, and which contains the sphere centered at **P** and of radius **r**.  In a general case this is a cuboid, though often it will be just a cube. After all, it kinda circumscribes a sphere. Let your cube be denoted **A**, and let this cuboid be denoted **B**. The answer to your problem lies inside both **A** and **B**. For this reason find the intersection **C**  of **A** and **B**. Focus entirely on **C**. This trick alone should result in a huge reduction of the problem complexity, with practically zero cost.

Now I assume you have a well written, well tested function   `distance(cube, point)`. Remember that the point on the `cube` that minimize the distance to `point` may lie on one of `cube`'s corners, edges, sides or its interior volume and so such a function will need several if-else branches.

Check if `distance` returns a value less or equal than `r`. If not, the answer is an empty set, you're done.

If the distance is <= r, then you can apply a modified method reported here by M.A., but applied to **C**. This **C** is not a cube, so octants are no solution here. However, **C** is a cuboid, for an intersection of 2 cuboids is a cuboid. Denote its side lengths as `Lx`, `Ly`, `Lz`. Thee numbers are **integers**, becassue now you measure the lengths in units of `dx`, `dy` and `dz` along axes `x`, `y`, `z`, repectively.   Find the largest of them. Suppose, for clarity, that it is `Lx`. If `Lx > 1` you divide **C** along the `x` axis into two equal-sized (when `Lx` is even) or almost equal (`Lx` is odd) sub-cuboids. You check the distance to each of them. If it is larger than `r` then you reject this whole sub-cuboid. Otherwise you repeat the division along the largest side of the current cuboid. This is very similar to, for example, implementation of the BVH tree.

Once you reached  the "sub-cuboid" of size 1x1x1, you verify if it intersects with the sphere. If yes, add it to the solution set.

* * *

This algorithm is very general because your question contains no details as to where the answer to this problem is to be used. For example, how large can  `n` be? Will the solution be used for fixed radius and varying sphere centers? Knowing such details could help develop a better solution.

For example, the sphere can contain O(N^3) cells, so one might expect that he solution cannot be found in time smaller than O(N^3). But perhaps you do nod a list of the cells? Perhaps a different format would do?

The set of cells forming the solution can be regarded as a union of disjoint columns of cells, oriented along the z axis. With this representation, the solution can be written as a set of pairs (`cell`, `height`). Here `cell` denote the lowest cell in a column, and `height` - its height. If a solution in this format is OK. the problem can be solved in O(N^2) or at mot O(N^2 log N) time.